# Android: add fragment dependency in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am using a number of DialogFraments in my Android app. To set up, I have imported "androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;" into each DialogFragment class. I have **not** added the Fragment dependency to the app's build.gradle file and the app is stable, working fine and the DialogFragments load and dismiss as expected.

Since DialogFragment extends Fragment though, should I be adding the below AndroidX Fragment library into the project's build.gradle file?  If yes, what is the benefit of adding this dependency since the app is working fine now without it?

```
build.gradle

dependencies {

    def fragment_version = "1.5.5"
 
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"
}


Existing build.gradle (:app) 

dependencies {

    def room_version = "2.4.3"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def work_version = "2.7.1"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.5.1"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already use fragments you apparently already have dependency that supports it, so no need to add another one.
You can post your gradle file so we can see which dependencies you already have.

Comment: @Pietrak I posted the existing build.gradle file above, please advise.

Comment: @AJW as far as I am concerned `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1` contains fragment dependencies. You can exclude them but unless anything specific - there is no need I think.